# If statement not working with classList add

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, ecmascript-6

i am making a navigation bar and want the class `active to be added when i am on that specific page
code bellow is not ruining with the if statement (shown with comment)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .active {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a  href="a.html" class="nav-item">nav</a>
  <a  href="b.html" class="nav-item">nav</a>
  <p id="z">aaa</p>
  <p id="zz"></p>

  <script>
  var navClass = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
  var path = window.location.href;

  for (i = 0; i < navClass.length; i++) {
//my issue
    if (navClass[i] === path) {
      navClass[i].classList.add("active");
    }
  }
  //for testing
  var xx = navClass[0];//.getAttribute("herf");
  document.getElementById("zz").innerHTML = xx + "<br>" + path;

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you expecting a full absolute url for path or are really expecting path (ex. `lib/b.html`) If the latter, then: `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables you are working with are formatted slightly differently than your code implies you are expecting them to be.

If you open up your console and access the window.location.href variable you'll see it contains a full valid URL, rather than relative format the links in your navigation follow, so your absolute test (===) will fail every time, as they will never be equal.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508836/if-statement-not-working-with-classlist-add
```

does not equal

```
if-statement-not-working-with-classlist-add
```

You could solve the problem by making the navigation links absolute, but that will cause more problems for you down the road.

If you change your test from comparing the two to looking for the navigation's href inside the path variable your code will work. Additionally, you'll need to test against the href attribute of your object, not the object itself.

Change:

```
if (navClass[i] === path) {
```

To:

```
if (path.includes(navClass[i].href)) {
```

Edited: Forgot to add .href attribute to suggested change

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how you're detecting, and how you're adding. Also make `navClass` an array, not a NodeList:

```
var navClass = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item"));
var path = window.location.href;

navClass.forEach(elem => {
    if (path.includes(elem.href)) {
        elem.classList.add("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: [*NodeLists*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) are iterable, so only convert to Array where *forEach* is not available. ;-) This doesn't address the primary issue, which is comparing relative and full URLs with `===`.